# Core Data: NSPredicate that looks in two Entities

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

The problem is that I don't know how can I make a `NSPredicate` that looks in two Entities. Any ideas?

### Let's assume I have 2 Entities:

```
Library:
1 lib_id
2 name
3 address
```

### and:

```
Books
1 book_id
2 book_name
3 book_author
4 lib_id
```

There isn't any Core Data Relation between them. I want to make a fetch request that will return an NSArray with all the libraries that contain at least one book.

### I assume it's something like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescriptor *entity = [NSEntityDescriptor entityForName:@"Books" inManagedObjectContext:context];
 // some NSPredicate...
array = [context executeFetch ...];
```

Comment: **Do NOT use the Xcode tag for questions unrelated to Xcode!**

Comment: Setup a relationship between the two entities. Create a request against `Library` with a predicate like `books.@count > 0`. In this manner, you can save time ;)

Comment: I can't create a relationship for some reasons...

Comment: If you cannot do what I suggested, you need to create two different requests: one for `Books` and one for `Library`. You need to load the two types of objects in memory and then perform some checking against the `lib_id`. Maybe other people could suggest other ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's more complicated than you think, but it's not impossible.

Your data model's use of `lib_id` on both entities, and your comment that you can't add a Core Data relationship between the entities, suggests you're falling into a classic trap: **You're treating Core Data like a relational database**. Core Data's API is not designed like a relational database. You can make it work that way, but you should be aware that **you are going out of your way to make Core Data more difficult than necessary**. If the solution below looks convoluted, it's because *you're doing Core Data wrong*.

If you were using Core Data as it's intended to be used-- in this case with a relationship between the two entities-- the lookup would be simple. You could just do a fetch for every `Library` with no entries in its `books` relationship.

With that said, you solve the immediate problem in two steps.

First, get every unique value of `lib_id` that's used on instances of `Books`. The following will get you an `NSArray` containing strings that match the unique values:

```
NSFetchRequest *bookRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Books"];
[bookRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"lib_id"]];
[bookRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[bookRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *libIdsInBooksDicts = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:bookRequest error:&error];
if (libIdsInBooksDicts == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@", error);
    return;
}

NSArray *libIdsInBooks = [libIdsInBooksDicts valueForKey:@"lib_id"];
```

The last line above is there because `libIdsInBooksDicts` actually contains an array of dictionaries, and each dictionary in turn has a key named `lib_id` and a value that's the actual ID. You just want the values.

Next, look up every `Library` whose `lib_id` is in the list you just got:

```
NSFetchRequest *libRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Library"];
[libRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lib_id in %@", libIdsInBooks]];

error = nil;
NSArray *librariesWithAtLeastOneBook = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:libRequest error:&error];
if (librariesWithAtLeastOneBook == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@", error);
    return;
}
```

Comment: +1 Tom. Good answer. I have already pointed out in my comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

`NSFetchedResultsController` can help in fetching results using a sectionNameKeyPath.

```
- (id)initWithFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest 
      managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context 
        sectionNameKeyPath:(NSString *)sectionNameKeyPath 
                 cacheName:(NSString *)name;
```

If you pass the lib_id as sectionNameKeyPath, you will get data in multiple sections, each section associating different lib_id.

Answer (score 0):

one fetch == one DISTINCT entity.

but you can have N related entities => letting one inheriting from one another

so .. you can have A1 extends A and A2 extends A:
    => A1 & A2 are stored in one table and they can be queried for in one fetch (fetch all As)

but .. you can not fetch for A and B that are unrelated:
    => cannot do it with one fetch